# For two multivariate function, do the functions always having the same value mean that the derivatives always have the same value?

Tags: matrices, vector-analysis

Let $f(X):\mathbb{S}^{n\times n}_{++}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g(X):\mathbb{S}^{n\times n}_{++}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two functions where $\mathbb{S}^{n\times n}_{++}$ means the positive definite cone. If $f(X)=g(X)$ for all $X\in \mathbb{S}^{n\times n}_{++}$, does $\nabla f(X)=\nabla g(X)$?

For a more specific problem, let $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\in\mathbb{S}^{2m\times 2m}_{++}$. $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ can be formulated as$$\boldsymbol{\Sigma}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\mathbf{A} & -\mathbf{B}\\
\mathbf{B} & \mathbf{A}
\end{array}\right],$$ where $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{S}^{m}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ is a skew symmetric real matrix. Let$$f\left(\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\mathbf{x}^T &
\mathbf{y}^T
\end{array}\right]\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{x}\\
\mathbf{y}
\end{array}\right]$$and$$g\left(\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-\mathbf{y}^T &
\mathbf{x}^T
\end{array}\right]\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}
-\mathbf{y}\\
\mathbf{x}
\end{array}\right].$$ We can easily figure out that $f\left(\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right)=g\left(\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right)$. However, since $$\nabla f\left(\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right)=-\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{x}\\
\mathbf{y}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\mathbf{x}^T &
\mathbf{y}^T
\end{array}\right]\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}$$and$$\nabla g\left(\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right)=-\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}
-\mathbf{y}\\
\mathbf{x}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-\mathbf{y}^T &
\mathbf{x}^T
\end{array}\right]\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1},$$ we may have $\nabla f\left(\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right)\neq\nabla g\left(\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right)$. Why does this happen?